# posting option box values populated by php

Tags: php, html

I have this section of code:

```
        <select id="frm_type" name="typeId">
                <?php foreach($product_types as $product) : ?>
                    <?php if ($product['id'] == $product_details['typeId']) $selected = " SELECTED"; else $selected = ""; ?>
                    <option value="<?=$product['id'];?>"<?=$selected;?>><?=$product['partNumber'];?> (<?=$product['title'];?>)</option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
```

This just populates a drop list/option box with data from a DB. This works fine in a form for create where an item is being selected and posted, however I want this same function on an edit page.

The edit page displays the currently selected values, and if unchanged, on post, nothing is posted from this input.

I believed the bits where I have used $selected... in the above, shows the selected option(which it does) it just doesnt send the selected data.

Could anyone offer any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<select id="frm_type" name="typeId">
<?php foreach($product_types as $product) : 
        $selected = ($product['id'] === $product_details['typeId'])
                    ? "selected='selected'"
                    : ""; 
?>
      <option value="<?=$product['id']?>" <?=$selected?> > 
         <?=$product['partNumber']?> (<?=$product['title']?>)
      </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: check your `$product_details` array first

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<select id="frm_type" name="typeId" disabled="disabled">
                <?php foreach($product_types as $product) : ?>
                    <?php if ($product['id'] == $product_details['typeId']) $selected = " selected='selected'"; else $selected = ""; ?>
                    <option value="<?=$product['id'];?>"<?=$selected;?>><?=$product['partNumber'];?> (<?=$product['title'];?>)</option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
```